# Showing a DataPager for a ListView only when there are at least 30 records

Tags: asp.net, listview, pagination, datapager

i ma using am listview and datapager control. in my list view i have specfied  to  show  30 records once  exceed **thirty  records** then  paging  comes where  rest of the resords  are  shown.

issue: when i  have  only  5  records  even then  my paging  is  shown(**previous 1 next**) even though the  link button are  disable of paging .  i do not  want to shown paging  untill i  exceed  thirty  records.

**i need to  shown the paging only when there is more than specfied  recoreeds to  be  shown in an page
 i do not want pging option to be  shown even if i have 1 or 30 records**

any help  would be great

thank  you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide a NextPreviousPagerField object in a DataPager control by setting the Visible property to false. You can also hide the individual buttons (the first-page, previous-page, next-page, and last-page buttons) by setting the ShowFirstPageButton, ShowPreviousPageButton, ShowNextPageButton, and ShowLastPageButton properties to false.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.nextpreviouspagerfield.aspx)
Good luck trying it out ;).
It will probably be something like

```
    if(results < 30) { DataPager1.Visible = false; }
```